# Regarding the STL string exception in multithreads application

Tags: c++, string, stl

when my application runs, I got one exception, and the stack is as below:

STACK_TEXT:

```
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
10f3dda0 7c96b3e5 0ab65a08 000000a4 07dd0000 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
10f3dfc8 7c98fb98 07dd0000 50000161 000000a4 ntdll!LdrAlternateResourcesEnabled+0x2ca6
10f3e04c 7c96b244 07dd0000 50000161 000000a4 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x749c
10f3e27c 7c939c0c 07dd0000 40000060 000000a4 ntdll!LdrAlternateResourcesEnabled+0x2b05
10f3e4b0 07b1e04e 07dd0000 40000060 000000a4 ntdll!RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection+0xad
10f3e4cc 07aef6a6 000000a4 d14f13ce 10f3e684 Camera!_heap_alloc_base+0x5e [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\malloc.c @ 105]
10f3e514 07aef42f 00000080 00000001 00000000 Camera!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl+0x1f6 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c @ 427]
10f3e534 07aef3cc 00000080 00000000 00000001 Camera!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl+0x1f [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c @ 239]
10f3e55c 07aef351 00000080 00000000 00000001 Camera!_nh_malloc_dbg+0x2c [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c @ 296]
10f3e57c 07a0e015 00000080 00000001 00000000 Camera!_malloc_dbg+0x21 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c @ 160]
10f3e598 079e68e1 00000080 10f3e76c 00000003 Camera!operator new+0x15 [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxmem.cpp @ 347]
10f3e684 079e5fee 00000080 00000000 10f3e870 Camera!std::_Allocate<char>+0x61 [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory @ 43]
10f3e76c 079e5dd7 00000080 d14f1e5a 10f3e96c Camera!std::allocator<char>::allocate+0x2e [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory @ 145]
10f3e880 079e5ac3 0000007b 00000000 10f3ea60 Camera!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Copy+0xc7 [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 2093]
10f3e96c 079e4d1c 0000007b 00000000 10f3eb50 Camera!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Grow+0x53 [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 2123]
10f3ea60 079e3e55 10f3ec48 00000000 ffffffff Camera!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign+0x8c [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 1055]
10f3eb5c 079fd484 10f3ec48 d14f1a52 10f3ee94 Camera!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >+0x75 [c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 724]
10f3ec88 079fd7a9 10f3ee60 00000000 cccccccc Camera!toLower+0xd4 [e:\tcom\camera\Camera\rtspurl1.cpp @ 61]
```

My tolow function is as below:

```
string toLower(string str)
{
  char* chartemp=(char*)malloc(str.length()+1);
  memset(chartemp,0,str.length()+1);
  memcpy(chartemp,str.c_str(),str.length());
  strlwr(chartemp);
  string lpUrl=chartemp;
  free(chartemp);
  return lpUrl;
}
```

I'm not clear that why the exception occurs when "return lpUrl".

Comment: Wut? std::string != C-style string

Comment: I recommend [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg me too, except for the fact that it can be actually tricky to get the correct overload of std::tolower (especially in C++03)

Comment: @sehe There is no overload of `tolower` which will work correctly with `transform`.  You have to wrap it in a functional object of sometime.

Comment: @JamesKanze that's basically my point. Even then, it could be exceedingly tricky to get the correct behaviour, but that's really beyond current scope (think sign extension and widening conversions). Arg. This stuff hurts my head :)

Comment: @sehe It's not difficult to get the correct behavior, once you know what the correct behavior is.  If you're doing any text processing at all, you'll have the functional objects in your toolkit (using `std::ctype<char>::tolower`, rather that `std::tolower`, so there won't be a `std::use_facet` for each use).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
string toLower(string str)
{
    for (size_t i =0; i<str.size(); ++i)
        str[i] = std::tolower(str[i]);
    return str;
}
```

I don't know about your reference to threading errors, because you don't show any information about that.

**Update** See live demo here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1d8b31ff73e2c2c9263ff5299dd4b7cb

Comment: Frankly, I can't be bothered to find out. Your question is tagged [tag:c++], and therefore I don't feel there is any need to dig through that maze of C-level code. Even in C, you'd just use `strdup` anyways....